# Procedural language plugin for PHP code

Tags: php, procedural-programming

I'm developing a web-based application for modelling and analysis of some manufacturing processes. I need to use capabilities of something like PL language in my PHP code. Is there any plug-in for PHP?

Comment: And curously enough object-oriented languages were first invented for the specific purpose of simulating processes such as manufacturing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP *is* a procedural language first, with OOP pretty much bolted on top of it (don't hate me for saying this other PHP guys!). You can write procedural code just fine in a PHP, it doesn't require a base initialisation/global class such as languages like C#, for example.

You can simply open up a new .php file and put all your code in there.

Whether this is recommended or not is an entirely different discussion ;-)

Comment: No real PHP programmer will deny that OOP is just bolted on; the ones who do are just in denial. ;)

Comment: @deceze Ah yes, but we know that most are :D

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are misunderstanding the concepts of Procedural programming. You should consider informing yourself a bit more and ask a more percise question with the right terms.

Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming) for more info about procedural programming.